# Android Libgdx SoundPool Memory Error

Tags: android, memory, libgdx, soundpool

In my game, done in libgdx I have 4 sounds. Three of them are below 1second, fourth is 3 second long played in loop. On start of the game all sounds are played correctly, but after while an attempt to play 4th one is causing an error with no sound played:

```
E/AudioFlinger(   67): not enough memory for AudioTrack size=525780
D/MemoryDealer(   67):   AudioTrack (0x51e58, size=1048576)
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     0: 00051e70 | 0x00000000 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     1: 0001b720 | 0x00003480 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     2: 0001ad18 | 0x00006900 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     3: 0001e4c0 | 0x00009D80 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     4: 0001b678 | 0x0000D200 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     5: 0001b350 | 0x00010680 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     6: 00051f00 | 0x00013B00 | 0x000805E0 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     7: 0001af00 | 0x000940E0 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     8: 0001b140 | 0x00097560 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):     9: 0001f800 | 0x0009A9E0 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):    10: 0001ba40 | 0x0009DE60 | 0x00006900 | F
D/MemoryDealer(   67):    11: 00051ce0 | 0x000A4760 | 0x00003480 | A
D/MemoryDealer(   67):    12: 0001bac8 | 0x000A7BE0 | 0x00058420 | F
D/MemoryDealer(   67):   size allocated: 660192 (644 KB)
```

And after some time the sound is back. Libgdx uses Android SoundPool for such effects. 
I have tried forcing GC from DDMS, although the gc was perfomed sound wasn't played.

[Libgdx Android Sound Implementation](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidSound.java)